# Will c++1y allow in-class initialization of base class variables from a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Instead of this:

```
class base
{
    protected:
        base( int value )
            : member{value}
        {}

        int member = 0;
};

class derived_1 : public base
{
    public:
        derived_1()
            : base{ 1 }
        {}
};

class derived_2 : public base
{
    public:
        derived_2()
            : base{ 2 }
        {}
};
```

This would be useful:

```
class base
{
    protected:
        int member = 0; // Default value
};

class derived_1 : public base
{
    base::member = 1; // Instead of passing it to a base class constructor
};

class derived_2 : public base
{
    base::member = 2;
};
```

Will c++1y support this, or similar, syntax?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this (actually, no one can have a better answer than "it probably will/won't" at this point), but I don't think this is useful or good for the language, as it would violate inheritance encapsulation. Consider that right now, you can't initialize base class member data in constructors...

Comment: @MartinJ. "...you can't initialize base class member data in constructors..." Yes you can.

Comment: @MartinJ.: One point should be noted that he has used protected in the base class not the private.

Comment: @DrTwox: Not in the derived class constructor, only by explicitly calling the base class constructor in the initializer list of the derived class constructor, which may in turn initialize base class member data in it's constructor.

Comment: I am talking about initialization, not assignment inside the constructor. Is this a new c++1y feature ? Because in C++11, this is just not valid...

Comment: @dalle: sure, but in this case, it's the base class's responsibility to initialize its own member data.

Comment: @MartinJ. Sorry, I misunderstood your statement and the difference between initializing and assignment. My mistake :)

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier to talk about this if we could post properly-formatted code in the comments ;)

Comment: I'm far from convinced that there is a point to your idea, in the first place. You do realize that what you have written in your two examples will produce EXACTLY the same resulting code, and the second example is longer to type, don't you? In other words, there is no benefit from it. [I'm of course relying on the compiler inlining the constructor, if you have complex constructors hidden in a separate compile unit, then it's a different story, but if the constructor is complex, you probably don't want to skip it...]

Comment: @MatsPetersson "...the second example is longer to type...". It is? It looks a lot more compact to me and clearer what is happening.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't see that you completely removed the constructors for the base and derived classes. I meant that `base::member = 1` is longer than `base(1)`. And what you describe really only helps if you have an extremely trivial class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are currently no plans to allow this. It seems a bit odd to allow an initializer to bypass a base class constructor (if any); it would seem to make more sense to allow a base-class specifier to contain an initializer:

```
class derived_1 : public base = {1}
{
};
```

You might consider [submitting a proposal](http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal), if you can explain how the language would benefit (do you have a concrete use case?).

As a workaround, you might consider using a class template:

```
template<int I = 0>
class base { protected: int member = I; };

class derived_1: public base<1> {};
```

If you need to preserve a common base class, use an intermediate base class template:

```
class base { protected: int member = 0; };

template<int I>
class base_init: public base { base_init() { base::member = I; } };

class derived_1: public base_init<1> {};
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but the rules on aggregates and aggregate initialization look likely to change in C++14: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html

Answer (score 0):

**No and Never.**

All fields of base class must be initialized in the constructor in base class. **Only** the constructor in base class know how its field should be initialized.

You can **and must** initialize an object or its fields through its constructor.

Comment: "Never", well you don't know that.